# Get specific value of a String

Tags: java

Using java Scanner class I'm getting a string as flows

```
    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/tmp/log.txt"));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();                

            //manipulate line      
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

String that I'm getting looks like

```
line = "[2013-12-02 10:13:47,125]: R="RUNNING.JOB.Q", 
REQUEST_UUID="7e1ed77c-afe3-992d-bc86-824ce73f4b6b", 
SRC_OBJ="ScheduledEvent.14060204",
DB2.QUERY_CT=22,
DB2.UPDATE_CT=1,
DB2.SVR_MS=52,
DB2.IO_MS=66, 
DB2.DRV_MS=74"
```

what I want is to get the value of the **"DB2.QUERY_CT"** (her 22) appreciate someone could help to get this values using string functions or any scanner functions.
NOTE: position of the **"DB2.QUERY_CT"** is not same always it getting change, here comma (,) use as the delimiter.

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what you've done to try and solve the problem; it currently reads like a request for code. Please share your attempted implementation and explain how it fails to meet your requirements.

Comment: @Duncan, What question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, code below, try to 1st find if DB2.QUERY_CT" is present or not and if yes, will obtain sub string from original string after "DB2.QUERY_CT=". So new value of line is  "=22, DB2.UPDATE_CT=1........" then will again get the sub string for this new String from 0 to 1st delimiter i.e. "," and thus find value of DB2.QUERY_CT.

I hope this helps

```
String line = "[2013-12-02 10:13:47,125]: R=\"RUNNING.JOB.Q\", REQUEST_UUID=\"7e1ed77c-afe3-992d-bc86-824ce73f4b6b\", SRC_OBJ=\"ScheduledEvent.14060204\", DB2.QUERY_CT=22, DB2.UPDATE_CT=1, DB2.SVR_MS=52, DB2.IO_MS=66, DB2.DRV_MS=74";
            String valueOf = "DB2.QUERY_CT";
            String delimiter = ",";
            String value = null;
            if (line.indexOf(valueOf) > -1){
                line =  line.substring(line.indexOf(valueOf) + valueOf.length() + 1);
                value  = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(delimiter));
                value = value.trim();
            }

            System.out.println("Value  " + value);
```

Comment: I got this right: it gets a sub-string starting from "DB2.QUERY_CT" value and from new sub-string it reads the value from 0 index to delimiter. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function to split the line at commas `,` into an array of Strings.
Then iterate over the new array, call a further split at the equal sign `=`, which will generate a String array of 2 elements. Just compare the first index with your search value and you're done.

Try it out and show us your code, if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest (quickest) solution here is to split your string around ", " and then iterate through the parts until you have one that starts with DB2.QUERY_CT. Then take the remaining string after the = . It's not pretty, but it would work. Other options include, using String.indexOf to find the position of your parameter, then the next , and substring the difference. Regular Expression, Something like .*DB2.QUERY_CT=(.*),.* then if it matches, get group 1 and you have your value.

Let me know if you need some pseudo/functional code for any of these.

Answer (score 1):

I won't show you a full solution, but here what you can do:

If this is a fixed format, you can use [`String#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to get the index of `"DB2.QUERY_CT="`, then (since you know the length of `DB2.QUERY_CT=`, you can know where the number begins and extract it.

Other solution would be using regex..